# Estimate a Fractal dimension of 2d image

Tags: image-processing, fractals

I want to estimate a value of Fractal dimension for some part of 2d image (photo).
How can I calculate estimation of this value, e.g. for 15x15 pixel subimage with rgb colors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat the pixel data as a surface in 5-space (one dimension each for X, Y, R, G and B), then do box-counting.

Update: [This](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/fraclac/FLHelp/BoxCounting.htm) is a pretty clear overview of box-counting in two dimensions, but it shouldn't be hard to generalise.

Comment: or should I switch to YUV space?

Comment: That depends on what you're going to do with it. I'd expect the information content of the R, G and B channels to be fairly similar. Switching to YUV would only make sense if you were expecting to be able to concentrate on a subset of channels, somehow.

Comment: Why -1? Who does this? The answer is good. Regularfry, please, add a link to box counting description.

Comment: Ok, I've added a link. Wikipedia has a few descriptions as well, but I liked this one.

Answer (score 1):

A hilbert curve has a fractal dimension of 2. A peano curve also. What image do you want to process? What kind of fractal do you want to use?

Comment: the image is a photo - so it is no binary image, but color image of some real object.

Comment: If you use a hilbert curve or a peano curve it's always 2. If you use a Sierpinksi fractal it's 1.26 (http://www.vanderbilt.edu/AnS/psychology/cogsci/chaos/workshop/Fractals.html). IMO it depends on the fractal you want to use.

Comment: epitaph, My question is not about image of fractal; but about random photo of any object and estimation of fractal dimensions of parts of the image.

Comment: Yes, sure but you still need to subdivide the image and also I asked you what kind of image do you want to process. What subdivision do you want?

Comment: I'll subdivide image into 15x15 subimages as mosaic