# What is the number of matching blocks in fractal image compression?

Tags: image, compression, fractals

to find number of block matching in fractal image compression,

i found this.

256x256 original image
16x16 sized parent blocks
241*241 = 58,081 block comparisons

but How this number(58,081) is calculated .

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a box counting algorithm for fractal dimensions:http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/fraclac/FLHelp/BoxCounting.htm. And here:[Estimate a Fractal dimension of 2d image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771519/estimate-a-fractal-dimension-of-2d-image), [estimate the fractal dimension of a complex network, provided the nodes of edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412029/estimate-the-fractal-dimension-of-a-complex-network-provided-the-nodes-of-edges).